# Germany Schengen visa with AirBnB booking

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, russian-citizens, airbnb

We (Russian citizens) are planning to go to Munich in late June. We would like to book our accommodation on AirBnB, but it is not very clear whether it will be accepted by the German embassy when we apply for a Schengen visa.

I can't find such information on the German embassy site or on the VFS-Global site. I've also searched for it on the Internet, and, while most sites agree that AirBnB booking is generally OK for a visa, I don't see a clear answer for Germany specifically, and there seems to be some exceptions for other European countries.

Comment: Note that *some* AirBnB apartments are illegal according to Munich zoning laws (one cannot simply turn a residential apartment into a hotel by listing it on a website).

Comment: (1) Book refundable hotel room on booking.com (2) obtain visa (3) get refund (4) profit!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, (5) get your visa cancelled, according to many comments on the Internet (e.g. https://ru-travel.livejournal.com/30450563.html?thread=358451331#t358451331 (in Russian))

Comment: @o.m., is there any way to find this in advance? Not regarding the visa question

Comment: @Petr I cancelled my air and hotel bookings for Germany and booked with another airline and hotel without issues.

Comment: @Petr there's really a rule that forbids altering your booking? That seems a perfectly normal thing to make, for many legitimate reasons.

Comment: @Petr, that will be difficult. It is legal to put a residential flat onto AirBnB while the owner is on vacation, but not year round. Or the flat may actually be for commercial purposes, then it is OK, too.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, it is OK to change your plans after you have a visa, even to visit an additional Schengen state if that is on the way. It is not OK to lie during the application. The difference can be hard to find or glaringly obvious, depending on the particular case.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, I found, for example, relevant note on Czech embassy site (in Russian): https://www.mzv.cz/moscow/ru/vizy_i_konsulskaja/vizovaja/schengenskaja/sengenskaja_turisticeskaja.html

The one before last paragraph says that one should inform the embassy if they change hotel booking after receiving visa, otherwise the visa can be cancelled. I guess that if I inform the embassy that I changed my booking to AirBnB one, and they don't like AirBnB, they would cancel anyway. And if they do like AirBnB, then I don't need to bother in the first place and can apply with AirBnB booking.

Answer (score 10):

Finally I've written email to VFS-Global, and they replied that AirBnB booking is OK. I understand that this is not absolutely official information, because VFS-Global are not German embassy, but I think it is official enough.

UPD: we got visa and had no problems at the airport at all. Though this is just one case, like with other similar posts on the Internet.

Comment: I believe it is interesting if you could attach an screenshot of the email that you received....

Comment: You probably should return back to this question after your trip and share your experience

Comment: The last time I visited, I cancelled my booking.com booking and booked on AirBNB. At the airport, the officials wanted to check all my bookings and tickets but did not object to AirBNB (or the change).